# How to put a QLabel on a stretched QPushbutton?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Firstly, look at the following:

[image]

I want to put the `label_3` on the `FontColor_btn` at the yellow rectangle, but the problem is that the `label_3` can't move it over the `FontColor_btn` because everything is stretchable even label_3 not in fixed size.

Again, **I want to put the `label_3` on the `FontColor_btn` at the yellow rectangle**?

Comment: Do you want to place a widget on another widget? Or would you just place a text inside the rectangle?

Comment: @eyllanesc:  place a widget on another widget (place the `label_3` on  the `FontColor_btn`).

Comment: That task can not be done through Qt Designer, you should do it through the programming as shown by @IlBeldus

Comment: @eyllanesc: Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible in designer, in code you just need to set the button as parent of the label and then move it:

```
QLabel* label3 =new QLabel(ui->fontColor_btn);
label3->setGeometry(/*move it where you want it*/);
```